# Is there a named method equivalent to $? in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, process

In Ruby, I'd like to access the status of the most recently executed external command's result information, that is, the information provided by `$?`, but would prefer a named method or variable. Is there such a thing, and, if so, how do I access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Process.last_status` returns the same Process::Status instance as `$?`:

```
$ irb
> `ls 12341234`
ls: 12341234: No such file or directory
 => ""
> $? == Process.last_status
 => true
> $?.equal? Process.last_status
 => true
> $?.class
 => Process::Status
```

**Thread Local**

Also, this variable is thread local, so each thread will have its own variable (i.e. threads will not overwrite a single global value). From the docs at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Process.html#method-c-last_status:

"Returns the status of the last executed child process in the current thread."

Comment: Your penultimate paragraph is pretty important. It is unfortunate that the "magic" global variables share the same sigil as "normal" global variables, but some magic global variables are actually thread-local, and some (like the `Regexp` match variables `$1`, `$2`, … `$9`) are even method-local.

Answer (score 1):

> would prefer a named […] variable.

The [`English`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/English.html) standard library provides descriptive aliases for `$?` and other special global variables. But unlike [`Process.last_status`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Process.html#method-c-last_status) this library has be loaded before any of its aliases can be used. The upside is it exists in Ruby < 2.5.

```
$ irb -rEnglish
> `ls 12341234`
ls: 12341234: No such file or directory
 => ""
> $? == CHILD_STATUS
 => true
> $?.equal? CHILD_STATUS
 => true
> $?.class
 => Process::Status
```